# How do I check with the assert command?

Tags: selenium

I am currently automating a web page with the [Selenium](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Selenium_%28software%29) webdriver. I am getting stuck now. I want to use the assert command for my script. Here is the screenshot of Add client module.

[image]

After entering client details it goes to another page. Here, I add a client name, "jason". Then click on submit and on the next page we can see the list of clients.

[image]

Here is the page source:

```
 <ul id="rightMenu" class="right">
            <li class="topmenu rtopmenu-display-event">
        <a href="javascript:void(0)"><span class=" ico fa fa-user"></span>Hello Administrator</a>
        <ul>
          <li><a href="http://doc.local/profile"><span class="ico fa fa-user"></span><span>Profile</span></a></li>
          <li><a href="http://doc.local/password/change"><span class="ico fa fa-key" style ="margin-right:7px;"></span>Change Password</a></li>
          <li><a href="http://doc.local/logout"><span class="ico fa fa-sign-out"></span>Logout</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>
      </ul>
</nav>
<div id="content">
  <div id="innerContent">
        <div class="bread-container">
      <ul class="bread-crumb">
                      <li>
         <a href="javascript:void(0)">
           Admin
         </a>
       </li>
                      <li>
         <a href="http://doc.local/admin/clients">
           Clients
         </a>
       </li>

       <li>
         <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="page-title">List Clients         </a>
       </li>
            </ul>
   </div>
   <div style="width:98%;" class="clearfix" id="search-container">
  <form class="form-inline">
    <div class="form-group">
      <input name="name" value="" size="13" placeholder="Company Name" class="form-control" />
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <input name="group_name" value="" size="12" placeholder="Group Name" class="form-control" />
    </div>
    <input type="submit" value="Search" class="btn btn-info" />
  </form>
  <a href="http://doc.local/admin/clients/add" class=""><i title="Add Client" class="fa fa-plus-square add-plus"></i></a>
</div>
<div style="width:98%;" id="list-container">
  <ul class="li-table">
    <li class="clearfix title header">
      <span style="width:3%;">&nbsp;</span>
      <span style="width:6%;">Si.No</span>
      <span style="width:20%;" class="">
        <a href="http://doc.local/admin/clients?&sort=ASC&order_by=name">Name</a>
      </span>
      <span style="width:20%;" class="">
        <a href="http://doc.local/admin/clients?&sort=ASC&order_by=group_name">Group Name</a>
      </span>
      <span style="width:28%;" class="">
        <a href="http://doc.local/admin/clients?&sort=ASC&order_by=registered_on">Registered On</a>
      </span>
      <span style="width:16%;" class="">
        <a href="http://doc.local/admin/clients?&sort=ASC&order_by=status">Status</a>
      </span>
    </li>
            <li  class="clearfix li-row  ">
      <span style="width:3%;">
        <a href="javascript:void(0)">
          <i class="fa fa-arrow-circle-o-down show-actions"></i>
        </a>
        <ul class="list-actions">
          <li><a href="http://doc.local/admin/clients/edit/1?"><i class="fa fa-pencil c-black"></i>Edit</a></li>
          <li><a class="delete-item" href="javascript:void(0)" rel="http://doc.local/admin/clients/delete/1?"><i class="fa fa-trash"></i>Delete</a></li>
        </ul>
      </span>
      <span style="width:6%;">1.</span>
      <span style="width:20%;">Demo&nbsp;</span>
      <span style="width:20%;">TBI&nbsp;</span>
      <span style="width:28%;">2nd Oct'15&nbsp;</span>
      <span style="width:16%;">Active&nbsp;</span>
    </li>
        <li  class="clearfix li-row even ">
      <span style="width:3%;">
        <a href="javascript:void(0)">
          <i class="fa fa-arrow-circle-o-down show-actions"></i>
        </a>
        <ul class="list-actions">
          <li><a href="http://doc.local/admin/clients/edit/4?"><i class="fa fa-pencil c-black"></i>Edit</a></li>
          <li><a class="delete-item" href="javascript:void(0)" rel="http://doc.local/admin/clients/delete/4?"><i class="fa fa-trash"></i>Delete</a></li>
        </ul>
      </span>
      <span style="width:6%;">2.</span>
      <span style="width:20%;">Jason&nbsp;</span>
      <span style="width:20%;">Tbi&nbsp;</span>
      <span style="width:28%;">28th Oct'16&nbsp;</span>
      <span style="width:16%;">Active&nbsp;</span>
    </li>
            <li class="clearfix title footer">
      <span style="width:3%;">&nbsp;</span>
      <span style="width:6%;">Si.No</span>
      <span style="width:20%;" class="">
        <a href="http://doc.local/admin/clients?&sort=ASC&order_by=name">Name</a>
      </span>
      <span style="width:20%;" class="">
        <a href="http://doc.local/admin/clients?&sort=ASC&order_by=group_name">Group Name</a>
      </span>
      <span style="width:28%;" class="">
        <a href="http://doc.local/admin/clients?&sort=ASC&order_by=registered_on">Registered On</a>
      </span>
      <span style="width:16%;" class="">
        <a href="http://doc.local/admin/clients?&sort=ASC&order_by=status">Status</a>
      </span>
    </li>
  </ul>
```

Here is the test script..

```
package Pages;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.FindBy;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.PageFactory;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.Select;

public class ClientPage
{
    private WebDriver driver;
    @FindBy(linkText="Admin")
    WebElement admin;
    @FindBy(linkText="Clients")
    WebElement clients;
    @FindBy(xpath="//*[@id='search-container']/a/i")
    WebElement search;
    @FindBy(id="name")
    WebElement name;
    @FindBy(id="groupname")
    WebElement groupname;
    @FindBy(id="address")
    WebElement address;
    @FindBy(id="status")
    WebElement status_dropdown;
    @FindBy(className="btn-primary")
    WebElement button;

    // Constructor
    public ClientPage(WebDriver driver)
    {
        PageFactory.initElements(driver, this);
    }
    public void set_Admin()
    {
        admin.click();
    }
    public void set_Client()
    {
        clients.click();
    }
    public void set_Search()
    {
        search.click();
    }
    public void set_Name(String nam)
    {
        name.clear();
        name.sendKeys(nam);
    }
    public void set_Groupname(String grp)
    {
        groupname.clear();
        groupname.sendKeys(grp);
    }
    public void set_Address(String add)
    {
        address.clear();
        address.sendKeys(add);
    }
    public void select_List(String status)
    {
        Select statusdropdown=new Select(status_dropdown);
        statusdropdown.selectByVisibleText(status);
    }
    public void set_Button()
    {
        button.submit();
    }
}


package Test;
import org.testng.annotations.Test;

import Pages.ClientPage;
import Pages.LoginPage;
import Pages.RolesPage;

import org.testng.Assert;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;
import org.testng.annotations.BeforeTest;

public class ClientTest
{
    WebDriver driver;
    @BeforeTest
    public void setup()
    {
        System.setProperty("webdriver.firefox.marionette","pathToGeckodriver");
        driver=new FirefoxDriver();
        driver.manage().window().maximize();
        driver.get("http://doc.loc");
    }
    @Test(priority=1)
    public void verify1()
    {
        LoginPage login=new LoginPage(driver);
        login.set_username("docm");
        login.set_password("1");
        login.click_button();
        Assert.assertTrue(driver.getPageSource().contains("Hello Administrator"));
    }
    @Test(priority=2)
    public void verif2()
    {
        ClientPage client=new ClientPage(driver);
        client.set_Admin();
        client.set_Client();
        client.set_Search();
        client.set_Name("Jason");
        client.set_Groupname("Tbi");
        client.set_Address("Ernakulam");
        client.select_List("active");
        client.set_Button();
    Assert.
    }
}
```

Comment: What's your concrete question?

Comment: @JB Nizet  sorry didn't understand

Comment: so you want to check if the added user is listed?

Comment: Ya right. After click on submit menu. I want to verify whether is result is passed or failed

Answer (score 0):

First, one would typically have your setup() method do the login, and include a teardown() which would logoff.  This keeps each test case is independent of the others.

Next, you'll need to define a page for the Client List.  This page would include a method findAllClients that returns a list of WebElements matching the rows in the client list.  Once you have that, you can use it in your verif2 test to check for a row that has the data you passed in when you created the client.